# How to fix Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL for liquibase

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, liquibase

I have a jhipster generated database, where I am trying to run this command:

```
mvn liquibase:diff
```

But right now I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.6.1:diff (default-cli) on project product: 
Error setting up or running Liquibase:
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Connection could not be created to hibernate:spring:com.moniesta.product.domain?dialect=&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy with driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.  Possibly the wrong driver for the given database URL
```

My database is running in docker and is configured like this in its docker-compose:

```
  products-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.28
    platform: linux/x86_64
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=products
    command: mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
```

This is how my pom is configured for the liquibase command:

```
               <configuration>
                        <changeLogFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                        <diffChangeLogFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/product?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;useSSL=false&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC&amp;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</url>
                        <username>root</username>
                        <emptyPassword>true</emptyPassword>
                        <referenceDriver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</referenceDriver>
                        <contexts>local</contexts>
                        <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.moniesta.product.domain?dialect=&amp;hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&amp;hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy</referenceUrl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <logging>error</logging>
                        <contexts>!test</contexts>
                    </configuration>
```

I see it tries to connect to the database correctly but the driver fails, but this is a mysql database so should the driver be not mysql.jdbc? I am using mysql8

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"?